# How can I convert org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to apply this idea https://fullstackml.com/how-to-check-hypotheses-with-bootstrap-and-apache-spark-cd750775286a to a dataframe I have. The code I'm using is this part:

```
import scala.util.Sorting.quickSort

def getConfInterval(input: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double], N: Int, left: Double, right:Double)
            : (Double, Double) = {
    // Simulate by sampling and calculating averages for each of subsamples
    val hist = Array.fill(N){0.0}
    for (i <- 0 to N-1) {
        hist(i) = input.sample(withReplacement = true, fraction = 1.0).mean
    }

    // Sort the averages and calculate quantiles
    quickSort(hist)
    val left_quantile  = hist((N*left).toInt)
    val right_quantile = hist((N*right).toInt)
    return (left_quantile, right_quantile)
}
```

This runs ok, but when I try to apply this to:

```
val data = mydf.map( _.toDouble )

val (left_qt, right_qt) = getConfInterval(data, 1000, 0.025, 0.975)

val H0_mean = 30
if (left_qt < H0_mean && H0_mean < right_qt) {
    println("We failed to reject H0. It seems like H0 is correct.")
} else {
    println("We rejected H0")
}
```

I get an error

> error: value toDouble is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Row val
>   data = dfTeste.map( _.toDouble )

And when I do it without the

```
.map( _.toDouble
```

I get:

> notebook:4: error: type mismatch;  found   :
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
>       (which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]  required:
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Double]

mydf is basically a dataframe that I selected only one column (that has type double, several rows of either 0.0 or 1.0)

When I do:

```
dfTeste.map(x=>x.toString()).rdd
```

It successfully it turns to org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] but I can't find a way to do this for Double. I'm very new to this so I apologize if it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Can you show the output of the following `val data = mydf.map( _.toDouble )`?

Comment: If `mydf` is a dataframe, then you should get an error when you define `data`

Comment: Yes, I fixed the post because I mixed the errors. I get an error on `mydf.map( _.toDouble )`and if I don't do the map I get the error of type mismatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently `val data = mydf.map( _.toDouble )` is not an `RDD[Double]` but a `DataFrame`

In the example you linked, they used

```
val data = dataWithHeader.filter( _ != header ).map( _.toDouble )
```

which is a `RDD[Double]` (`sc.textFile` returns a RDD)

So you need to convert `mydf` to an RDD, you can do this with e.g. :

```
val data = mydf.map(r => r.getDouble(0)).rdd
```